# Open Latex project downloaded from Overleaf to TexMaker?

Tags: texmaker, overleaf

I've downloaded my existing project from overleaf containing multiple subfolders and images.
Unfortunately, when I now try to import it to TexMaker it doesn't let me the option to import the whole folder, rather one file at a time, with no option to import images as well.
It resulting in `file XXX not found` on multiple files, although they live in the same directory as the file being imported.

Is there a way of defining the "working directory" for TexMaker?

Comment: Usually the location of your main `.tex` file would be the working directory and all relative file names will be resolved relative to that directory. TeXmaker doesn't need to open all your other files. It is enough if they are present in your document folder. So I'd expect things to work if you just download all your files from Overleaf onto your local machine and make sure the file structure is the same as on Overleaf (so if you have a subfolder on Overleaf with images in it, you need a subfolder of your document directory with the same name as on Overleaf).